# Shell validated kinit/keytab gets "Invalid Syntax" error in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kerberos

Very odd, why when I kinit with my keytab, it reports 
"Invalid Syntax" error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) Put an exclamation mark (`!`) before kinit, so Jupyter recognizes this as a shell command and not a Python code

2) You most likely will need a kerberos realm after username. So last argument to kinit should be something `rxie@SOME.DOMAIN.COM` (this is known as a Kerberos principal name), not just `rxie`